# C# Open SQLite file

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

i would like to open SQLite DB file in C#.

I have this code rewrited from Visual Basic source code.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\web.db;";
myConnection.Open();
```

but i can't open the file 'web.db' on local computer in C# Console Application.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the [SQLite ADO.NET driver for .NET](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) or something similar.

Comment: @dESource: I've updated it to *a* SQLite ADO.NET driver; I don't know whether it's the same one that I referred to 7 years ago though...

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. Yeah that's the same I've tried couple of time but no luck, don't understand this  issue is with the binary or VS. I have the following error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
I installed SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.0.0.0 then I came across with this error:You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().'. Long back it use to work fine though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NuGet in Visual Studio to install the offical System.Data.SQLite drivers created by the SQLite development team.