# Open .sqlite file with C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Hi i have a file called   test.sqlite. How do i go about reading all contents from this file to the console? I already have System.Data.Sqlite

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           SQLiteConnection _SQL = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\test.sqlite");

           _SQL.Open();

           SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

        }
```

Comment: sounds like a similar question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292654/c-sharp-open-sqlite-file

Comment: What do you mean by "file called test.sqlite", is it a database of extension ".db3" or some other.

Comment: SqLite is a database.  Why would you want to read its entire contents to the console?  That's not normally what you do with a database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use SQLite in your C# application, you need to download a third party free ADO.NET data provider [SQLite.NET.0.21_x68_dll](http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/).

You can download it from here: [Sql Lite Driver for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx)

and here is another usefull video tutorial which you must watch: [System.Data.Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this the answer? He's already using System.Data.SQLite.