# Open SQLite database in C# WITHOUT installing anything

Tags: c#, sqlite, portability, portable-applications

I am writing a portable C# application designed to be run as a single executable file on a USB.  It needs to be able to extract some data from a SQLite database.  Because it is portable, installing something locally is not an option.  I have seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178195/open-sqlite-file-with-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292654/c-sharp-open-sqlite-file) but they require installing third party software.

How can I get this data without losing the portability?

**Edit:**
I tried using the System.Data.SQLite NuGet package.  It works, but then suddenly I have gone from a single executable file to an executable, a .dll and two additional folders.  I can deal (albeit unhappily) with a single dll addition, but that is too much.

Comment: You don't really need to install anything. Just download an additional dll and have it present with you program.

Comment: [This](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) looks like a little more than a single dll

Comment: Since the source code is available - you could integrate the managed dlls (System.Data.SQLite.dll and System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll) into your own dll. You'll still be left with 1 or 2 native dlls files. Why do you care so much for the number files?

Comment: @Vadim The idea of this program is that it can easily be transferred, copied, moved around, etc. as simply as possible. Having multiple files complicates things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use [IlMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).
2. [Embed an assembly as a resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56197/Embed-an-Assembly-as-a-Resource).

Answer (score 0):

Well I think is about as good as it is going to get: I got it down to a single executable and a single dll file.

To do this I changed the architecture of the executable from Any CPU to x86 only, and then installed the "System.Data.SQLite.x86" NuGet package.

If anyone knows how to keep the capability but in a single executable file, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try Costura.Fody (browse on Nuget Packages), i usually use this one and it packs everything in a single exe, i believe it should work.